# Oracle Apex SQL Create View

Tags: sql, oracle, view, oracle-apex

How to stop a multi-table view from updating an underlying table?

to be specific here is the question:

Create a VIEW to list holiday IDs, holiday description and countries. The view should also include a column that lists USA as “America”, India as “Asia”, China as “Asia”, and Spain as “Europe”; **but your solution must not update or add to data in the tables**. Make sure you supply the full SQL statement showing the view creation. Write a SELECT statement to test the view.

```
Create or replace view v_holiday as
select "DETAILS_OF_HOLIDAY"."HOLIDAYCODE" as "HOLIDAYCODE",
       "DETAILS_OF_HOLIDAY"."COUNTRYVISITED" as "COUNTRYVISITED",
       "DETAILS_OF_HOLIDAY"."HOLIDAYDESCRIPTION" as "HOLIDAYDESCRIPTION" 
from "DETAILS_OF_HOLIDAY" "DETAILS_OF_HOLIDAY"
```

Comment: "but _your_ solution must not update or add to data in the tables"...Homework?

Comment: Yes, part of an individual research project

Comment: The assignment does not appear to be asking you to do anything to prevent updates.  It appears, rather, to ask you to use the view to display the data differently than it appears in the table.  Most likely by employing an appropriate `CASE` statement in the view.

Comment: Your right in the sense it does want us to display data differently, however, it clearly stated "BUT YOUR SOLUTION MUST NOT UPDATE OR ADD TO DATA IN THE TABLES"

Comment: That means don't just change the data in the table to suit your use. It means add a new column in the view that uses either a CASE, IF/ELSE, or DECODE logic to display additional info. I would recommend the Oracle DECODE statement.

Comment: Thanks, "Decode" really helped, thats rarely talked about on some of the major sites like w3schools and techonthenet

Comment: There is a READ ONLY option with views if you don't want your view to be updateable. w3schools isn't going to mention DECODE since that's an SQL function. CASE is the ANSI standard.